# reading a file and getting the MD5 hash in python

Tags: python

The loop is working but once I put the if statements in it only prints `I am a dir`

If the if statements are not there I am able to print the `dirpath, dirname, filename` to the console

I am trying to list all the file names in a directory and get the MD5 sum.

```
from os import walk
import hashlib
import os
path = "/home/Desktop/myfile"

for (dirpath, dirname, filename) in walk(path):

    if os.path.isdir(dirpath):
        print("I am a dir")
    if os.path.isfile(dirpath):
        print(filename, hashlib.md5(open(filename, 'rb').read()).digest())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only checking `dirpath`. What you have as `dirname` and `filename` are actually collections of directory names and files under `dirpath`. Taken from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories), and modified slightly, as their example removes the files:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Will print the list of of directories and files under `top` and then will recurse down the directories in under `top` and print the folders and directories there.

Answer (score 1):

From the Python documentation about os.walk:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

> dirpath is a string, the path to the directory. dirnames is a list of
>   the names of the subdirectories in dirpath (excluding '.' and '..').
>   filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in
>   dirpath.

With `os.path.isfile(dirpath)` you are checking whether `dirpath` is a file, which is never the case. Try changing the code to:

```
full_filename = os.path.join(dirpath, filename) 
if os.path.isfile(full_filename):
    print(full_filename, hashlib.md5(open(full_filename, 'rb').read()).digest())
```